# Set File Association

Tags: file-association

There's a certain file type that I have that I can't open. I'm not sure why, but this file type lost its association with Winrar, which used to be the default program for opening it. I tried looking for the file type in Default Programs, but it wasn't there and I don't know how to add a new file type. I right-click on the file type and select "Open with" and choose Winrar, but nothing happens.

Comment: What is the file extension?

Comment: i'm not sure your question could be any more vague.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the WinRar settings dialog ( Options -> Settings... ):

[image]

Check the correct box on the left and hit OK.